# $\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}$ is nowhere dense.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open set in a metric space $X$, then $\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}$ is nowhere dense.

Therefore, I need to show that $\left(\overline{\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}}\right)^c$ is dense, or rather

$$
\left(\overline{\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}}\right)^c=X\iff
\overline{\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}}=\emptyset.
$$
But I'm not sure where to go from this.

Comment: Can you show $\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}$ is closed?  The part after "or rather" is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\overline{\mathcal{O}}\setminus\mathcal{O}$ : it is closed so $\overline{A}=A$. So you just have to prove that $A$ has empty interior.

But $\mathring{A} \subset A \subset \overline{\mathcal{O}}$, so if $\mathring{A} \neq \emptyset$, you must have $\mathring{A} \cap \mathcal{O} \neq \emptyset$, which is absurd since $A \cap \mathcal{O} = \emptyset$. So $\mathring{A}=\emptyset$ and you are done.

Comment: Why is $A$ closed? I know that $\mathcal{O}$ open (by hypothesis) and that $\overline{\mathcal{O}}$ is closed.

Comment: @D.Math $\overline{\mathcal O} \setminus \mathcal O = \partial \mathcal O$

Comment: @D.Math You can write $A = \overline{\mathcal{O}} \cap (X \setminus \mathcal{O})$ which is closed as an intersection of two closed sets.

Comment: The boundary is a closed set. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157255/the-boundary-is-a-closed-set

Comment: Could you add a proof if $F$ is closed then $F\setminus F^o$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: The same proof works ! @D.Math